# GUI library for handling primitives and arrays/collections of primitives

Tags: java, swing

I have built many *many* GUI:s and I don't like to have dependencies to libraries so I end up doing much of the basics myself. One thing that I end up doing over and over again is mapping primitives to GUI components.

For example if it is a `boolean` I often use `JCombobox` with two options (`"true"`, `"false"`) and if it is `int` I use a `JTextField`. Much of the work is to go from and to text...

Some example mappings:

- `int` or `Integer` => `JTextField` or `JSpinner`
- `boolean` => `JTextField`, `JComboBox` or `JCheckBox`
- `int[]` => `JList` (with "add" field and "remove" buttons)
- `Set<Byte>` => probably the same as arrays

---

So, to the questions:

- Is there already a library that have mappings like this or do I need to "invent" it again?
- I have seen [jfg](http://code.google.com/p/jfg/) that uses refection and SWT as frontend (you can implement a new frontend using swing but that is exactly what I'm trying to avoid). Is there a simular library that uses swing and refection?

Comment: Guess boolean should be mapped to JCheckBox or JToggleButton. But questions is good +1

Comment: This reminds me of how `JTable` picks renderers and editors.

Comment: As with `JTable`, you can use [*Class Literals as Runtime-Type Tokens*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html) to minimize the risk of reflection.

Answer (score 2):

there are 2 binding libraries i've had some experience with:

1. [glazed lists](http://www.glazedlists.com/) - this library absolutely shines when you want to map a Collection to a jtable (one item per row, columns are attributes of the object).
2. [jgoodies binding](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/binding/) - a more general-purpose library for mapping bean attributes to gui elements. its a bit more complex and difficult to pick up.

and why primitives? im assumming you store your model (the set of all values being displayed/edited by the gui) in one or more Objects no? if so, you could rely on autoboxing and work with object wrappers in the gui.

Answer (score 1):

One should mention **JavaFX**, which is still not my beer.

Answer (score 0):

You might find it interesting to take a look at [seesaw](https://github.com/daveray/seesaw) which is a GUI library for Clojure baseed on Swing.

It does a pretty good job of wrapping Swing functionality in pretty simple functions - some good design ideas even if you don't end up using it directly. For example, it can bind controls directly to mutable data objects:

```
; Bind a the value of a slider to an atom, with a transform
; that forces the value to [0, 1]
(let [s (slider :min 0 :max 1)
      a (atom 0.0)]
  (bind s (transform / 100.0) a))
```